# Specifying vertical text height

Tags: html, css

I am building a horizontal menu using unordered lists. 4 items are links and then there's an image in the center. Currently the links are centered on the middle of the image, but the I would rather the text vertically align lower than middle. The image is 140px tall and I would like the text to be at 50px. I've tried playing with vertical-align and line-height, but no joy. Padding doesn't work. I'm sure this is obvious and I'm just missing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```css
.menu {
  text-align: center;
}
.menu ul {
  display: inline-table;
}
.menu ul li {
  display: inline;
  line-height: 0px;
}
.menu .link {
  padding: 15px;
}
.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #131313;
}
.menu a:hover {
  color: #330000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="link"><a href="menu.html">MENU</a>
      </li>
      <li class="link"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="link">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img class="center logo" src="https://placehold.it/140x140" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="link"><a href="/blog">BLOG</a>
      </li>
      <li class="link"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using bootstrap 3.3.6 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugs5tm5j/1/)?

```css
.menu { text-align:center; }
.menu ul { display:inline-table;}
.menu ul li {display:inline; line-height:0px;}
.menu .link {
 padding: 15px;
}
img{
  width: auto;
  height: 140px;
  vertical-align: -50px;
}
.menu a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #131313;
}
.menu a:hover {
 color: #330000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="link"><a href="menu.html">MENU</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="index.html"><img class="center logo" src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300"/></a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="/blog">BLOG</a></li>
        <li class="link"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the text `LI`'s a different class, and then apply `vertical-align: 50px`.

```css
.menu {
  text-align: center;
}
.menu ul {
  display: inline-table;
}
.menu ul li {
  display: inline;
  line-height: 0px;
}
.menu .link {
  padding: 15px;
}
.menu .link.align {
  vertical-align: 50px;
}
.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #131313;
}
.menu a:hover {
  color: #330000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="link align"><a href="menu.html">MENU</a>
      </li>
      <li class="link align"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="link">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img class="center logo" src="https://placehold.it/140x140" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="link align"><a href="/blog">BLOG</a>
      </li>
      <li class="link align"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want the text to be `vertical-align: top` or `vertical-align: middle` but you can adjust it as you please with this [codepen](http://codepen.io/chuddayo/pen/rxXgPd)!

I made the li's inline-block which enables them to be adjusted by the vertical-align property and still be horizontal across your navigation.

I gave the background some color so that the stock image wouldn't blend in as much and you'd be able to see the alignment.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="link"><a href="menu.html">MENU</a></li>
    <li class="link"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li class="link"><a href="index.html"><img class="center logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/140/200/"/></a></li>
    <li class="link"><a href="/blog">BLOG</a></li>
    <li class="link"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #BBB;
}

.menu { 
  text-align:center; 
}
.menu ul { 
  display:inline-table;
}
.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.menu .link {
    padding: 1em;
}

.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 3.125em;
    color: #131313;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #330000;
}
```